# warcraft 3 frozen throne bonus campaign cairn last hero ability point

Tags: warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

I'm replaying Warcraft 3 frozen throne bonus campaign and I remember that in my previous playthroughs, Cairn the tauren always has one hero ability point missing.

Is that how it's supposed to be? or am I missing something?

EDIT: I will try to clarify, the other heroes which are Rexxar, Rokhan and Chen get 18 hero ability points total from leveling up and clearing quests. On the other hand, Cairn gets only 17. With 18 points I can max out the heroes abilities (3 spells * 4 levels + bonus stats * 4 levels + 1 ultimate * 2 levels). In my previous playthroughs, I get an ability point as a reward from the main quest right before  Cairn who ends up missing one point.

Comment: whats your problem? is that not the case anymore? if it is and was that way, it's probably intended

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I want to know whether or not I'm missing something. If I knew I wouldn't be asking a question in the first place...

Comment: ok. then please clearify your question. I don't know what you want to know.

Comment: There is a **Tome of Power** located in `OrcX02_03`, _Theramore Isle_.  It will give one hero an additional level — unknown if it would be wasted were they at or too near an exp limit for the campaign.  You don't have Cairne at this time, and I don't think you can revisit there when you complete the _Escape Theramore_ quest, but perhaps that Tome was meant to play in the allocation somehow.